next navigation not found doesn't get the wanted not found page
In my next js server, I handle multiple domains in the middleware so that when a request comes from a "universal domain" I dynamically change the nexturl pathname so it returns a specific page in my app tree, here the universal [...urlParts] page. The problem is that when i call the notFound function from next/navigation in the universal page, it doesn't return the closest not found page which would be the ont in my universal directory but it actually returns the one from the app root directory
To set the locale of a universal page, I fetch the page from a service and set it with unstable_setRequestLocale inside my page.tsx before calling the not found
Current packages versions:
  next: 14.2.6
  eslint-config-next: 14.2.6
  react: 18.3.1
  react-dom: 18.3.1
  typescript: 5.0.4


const withUniversal: MiddlewareFactory = (next: NextMiddleware) => {
    return async (request: NextRequest, _next: NextFetchEvent) => {
        if (request.nextUrl.pathname === "/robots.txt") {
            return NextResponse.next();
        }

        const hostname = getHostNameFromRequest(request);
        if (
            request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/api/") ||
            request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/assets/") ||
            request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/favicon/") ||
            request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/~partytown/") ||
            request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next/static") ||
            request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next/image") ||
            request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/universal")
        ) {
            return await next(request, _next);
        }

        if (
            Object.values(UniversalDomains).includes(
                hostname as UniversalDomains
            )
        ) {
            const newPath = "/universal/" + hostname + request.nextUrl.pathname;
            request.nextUrl.pathname = newPath;
            
            return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(newPath, request.url));
        }
        const response = await next(request, _next);
        return response;
    };
};

.
├── [locale]
│   ├── (published_apps)
│   ├── demo
│   ├── not-found.tsx
│   └── page-renderer
├── api
│   ├── auth
│   ├── embeddable
│   ├── hello
│   ├── newsletter
│   ├── preview-deployments
├── layout.tsx
├── not-found.tsx
├── test.txt
└── universal
    ├── [...urlParts]
    │   ├── layout.tsx
    │   └── page.tsx
    ├── layout.tsx
    └── not-found.tsx

 ✓ Ready in 1341ms
 ✓ Compiled /middleware in 203ms (123 modules)
 ○ Compiling /universal/[...urlParts] ...
 ✓ Compiled /universal/[...urlParts] in 8.1s (7501 modules)

Unable to find `next-intl` locale because the middleware didn't run on this request. See https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware#unable-to-find-locale. The `notFound()` function will be called as a result.

 GET /dbaizuvd 404 in 10150ms
 ○ Compiling /_not-found ...
 ✓ Compiled /_not-found in 3.8s (7504 modules)
 GET /favicon/favicon.co 404 in 3938ms

I tried to Manually set in the layout a NextIntlClientProvider with a locale
I tried to get the page directly without the url translation (http://localhost:3000/universal//ezfbaizeu) but still got the base not found page at the root of my app directory
